# Убрать index.php с помощью htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Без использования htaccess мой URL выглядит так: `http://site.ru/index.php?page=1`.

Как с помощью htaccess, сделать из этого, такой вариант: `http://site.ru/1`?

Answer (score 1):

взято из комментария.

---

```
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: я так сделал, но  у меня не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

или так

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1
```

P.S. Пишу на память, но вроде работать должно.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то оба варианта приведут к циклической переадресации.

Comment: void. К сожалению ваш вариант не работает.:-(

Comment: .

    RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

Comment: ReinRaus. Благодарю вас! Вариант рабочий.

Comment: Прошу прощения что не смог поправить - только добрался до компа. Да, мой вариант не то, собирался написать аналогичный правильному, который уже указал @ReinRaus, но уже опередили ))

Comment: Внесу тогда и свою лепту, может и пригодится - иногда требуется делать статический `Rewrite`, когда `site.ru/1` требуется прикрутить к конкретной странице, а `site.ru/2` - к другой, то тогда подойдет следующий вариант

    RewriteRule ^[1]{1}?$ index.php?page.php=1
    RewriteRule ^[2]{1}?$ other.php?action=start 
    RewriteRule ^[3]{1}?$ abc.php?id=5&item=555&sort=price

Здесь используется проверка числа и его длины.

Comment: Можно упростить:  


    ^[1]{1}?$
До:  

    ^1?$
Что немного не корректно, так как пропустит пустое значение или одну единицу.  
Правильно конечно:  

    ^1$
Аналогично с остальными.  
**Добавлено**  
Споткнулся на смешной ошибке:  

   ^[1]{1}?$
Полностью равносильно:  

   ^1$
Потому что вопросительный знак здесь выступает в роли указания, что квантификация с минимальной жадностью.